# Using hit test to not detect hit behind view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view cell that has a button on the top of the view so that part of it not in the cell. So i have done this in side the custom tableview cell class. -

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        if CGRectContainsPoint(buttonA.frame, point) {
            buttonAPressed()
            return true
        } else if CGRectContainsPoint(buttonB.frame, point) {
            buttonBPressed()
            return true
        } else if CGRectContainsPoint(buttonC.frame, point) {
            buttonCPressed()
            return true
        }

        return super.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)
    }
```

So that the button hits are detected for the buttons. The problem is that I also have a big button behind the tableview. The problem is that the button behind is also detected as being pressed. Is there a way to stop the behind button from being pressed?

Comment: can you please show a screenshot?

Comment: `bigButton.enabled = false` ??